# Train networks on which every point is visited after a finite time

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for the set of all train networks fulfilling the following property: There is a maximum time after which a moving train revisits each part of the track, no matter what turn it takes at switches.

For example the following network does not fulfil the conditions, as a train could forever stay in the left half:

[image]

Tracks may cross each other with bridges or similar. However, I would not consider two networks that only differ in terms of such crossings distinct in the sense of my question. With other words, I consider networks equivalent, if they have the same arrangement of switches and connections between them.

If I am not mistaken, only the following two networks fulfil my conditions:

[image]

I could prove this using a lot of case distinctions, but I am wondering whether there is a more elegant proof, which is what I am asking for here.

Comment: If the second network forces a train to visit both loops, then why not have a third loop, connected to the second by the same type of connection?

Comment: @vadim123: If I correctly understand what you are suggesting, the train could always pass the middle “loop” on the top half and thus never visit the bottom half.

Comment: if the switches changed randomly the trains will visit any finite connected network in expected finite time. However, if the switches are designed "evilly" as you describe in your situation, then you are right, the only networks the trains need to visit entirely are the ones you describe. You could simply prove it by contradiction, just add anything else to your networks and you'll get your condition violated

Comment: @moonshine: *You could simply prove it by contradiction, just add anything else to your networks and you'll get your condition violated* – You cannot just assume that a possible third network contains the existing two as a sub-network – in fact, that’s easy to disprove, as the train could always stay on the sub-network and thus not visit what you added.

Comment: There are actually infinitely many graphs that satisfy this property. The book to read is "Combinatorics of train tracks" by Robert Penner.

Comment: @studiosus: Thanks. However, I suspect that you misunderstood my criterion since I am rather skeptical about there being infinitely many such graphs as any graph with this property cannot have a subgraph with this property. Can you give one example which I missed or show the flaw in San’s answer?

Comment: how can we test if a graph is a train network ? it is a matter of connected components, right ?

Comment: @user1952009: It’s a graph where each node has a degree of three and one special edge (the end of a switch which can be reached from both other ends).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft : I don't get it. you are talking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path ? I don't see how it answers

Comment: @user1952009: *you are talking of en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path?* It’s related to Eulerian paths, but it’s not the same. Nodes and edges may be visited more than once (and indeed are in the second solution) and there are rules on how you may progress on an edge (because that’s how train switches work). — *I don't see how it answers* – what are you referring to?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft : you don't get it. in a real-life train network there are different tracks, while the graph you drew are not oriented : I think a train network is an oriented graph, with only one connected component.

Comment: *in a real-life train network there are different tracks, while the graph you drew are not oriented : I think a train network is an oriented graph, […]* – [You are very much mistaken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-track_railway).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Sorry, I was confused, I think san's solution is correct.